# Gradient effect on some portion of UIImageView

Tags: ios, cagradientlayer, uiblureffect

I have a requirements of adding gradient over some portion (only in left and right side ) of UIImageView.
I know, this can be done by using CAGradientLayer(). But I am confused with properties locations and colors.

Below is my code. It is adding gradient at top and bottom.

```
 if let containerView = imageView.superView {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: containerView.layer)
        gradient.frame = containerView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor ,UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 ,  0.25 , 0.85 , 1.0]
        containerView.layer.mask = gradient
    }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you share result of this code ? and what do you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `CAGradientLayer` layer like this and in Any view

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,300, 380)
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red:55.0/255, green:149.0/255, blue:227.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor,UIColor(red:20.0/255, green:77.0/255, blue:120.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
imgView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

For All direction like `top-buttom`,`left-right` and vice versa just you need to change `startPoint` And `endPoint`
Output of above code is

[image]

Comment: Above code adds gradient in bottom of your view, But I want to add gradient  in left and right side of my view.

Comment: Will be really helpful for me

Comment: for All direction just you need to change startpoint And End point 
for left to right
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

Comment: Have you try my Answer?

Comment: Hi Jignesh, Thanks a lot, I tried your answer.
Now I am able to add gradient in left and right side of my view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129990/discussion-between-sundeep-saluja-and-jignesh-vadadoriya).

Comment: Jignesh, Can you please tell me about colors also
?
actually, I need to add a white color with alpha 0.5(almost half opaque) to both side(left and right)

Comment: can you add image which you want in color please

Comment: Not aware, Can I add image , here in comments?

Comment: join me in chat room where you can upload image

Answer (score 0):

`gradient.colors`

> `gradient.colors`property is used to define the color of each gradient

If you see the documentation,

> `gradient.locations` is used to define gradient stop points between your colors
>
> *Documentation*: An optional array of NSNumber objects defining the location of each gradient stop as a value in the range [0,1]

is this you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I saw the documentation, But not able to guess, exact location for left and right side.