# ios UIView for complete viewController frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am beginner for ios and I want to create a UIVew as like Image. You can observe a white color from one place to another place in the attached image. How can I achieve it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23074539/1891327

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013702/gradient-effect-on-some-portion-of-uiimageview/41014007#41014007

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UIView *) returnGradientView {
     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
     CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
     gradient.frame = view.bounds;
     //change your color as you like, I have used black and white
     gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
     [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
     return view;
}
```

**Edit**

this will create an gradient view, upper side white and lower side is black. if you want to make `top-bottom` or `left-right` you have to add `startPoint` and `endPoint`

just add two line

```
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```